# How to remove extra blank line under command-line in vim/macvim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I am getting this empty blank line below command-line. I had vim-airline installed but even after uninstalling it, the blank line is still there. (In full-screen mode)

[image]

With Airline installed

[image]

With Airline uninstalled

I have also tried to check `cmdheight` with `:set cmdheight?` and it is set to one in either case. Like wise `:set laststatus?` is also one.

When I exit out of full-screen the window will not resize below command-line.
[image]

How do I get rid of this blank line and possibly keep vim-airline?

Comment: probably you should ask in the airline's issue-tracker

Comment: @Kent, thank you for your reply! I have uninstalled airline but the issue is still there. So, I guess it is independent from airline.

Comment: have you tried to disable all plugins and custom settings, is the problem still there?

Comment: It sounds like the height of the terminal is not exactly aligned to the number of pixels per character; i.e., there are extra pixels at the bottom, but not enough for a full line of text (in height), so you have some blank space. Try resizing your terminal or playing with font-sizes/gaps

Comment: @Kent, no, I will try disabling all the plugins and see what happens.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I see. Let me play with font-sizes/gaps.

Comment: This is quite common problem when using vim inside the terminal, its because of font size as @D.BenKnoble said.